# Grant access to RDS layer using Cloudformation for app layer

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I have an RDS database that I bring up using Cloudformation.  Now I have a Cloudformation document that brings up my app server tier.  How can I grant my app servers access to the RDS instance?

If the RDS instance was created by my Cloudformation document, I know I could do this:

```
"DBSecurityGroup": {
        "Type": "AWS::RDS::DBSecurityGroup",
        "Properties": {
            "EC2VpcId" : { "Ref" : "VpcId" },
            "DBSecurityGroupIngress": { "EC2SecurityGroupId": { "Fn::GetAtt": [ "AppServerSecurityGroup", "GroupId" ]} },
            "GroupDescription"      : "Frontend Access"
        }
    }
```

But the DBSecurityGroup will already exist by the time I run my app cloudformation.  How can I update it?

**Update** Following what huelbois pointed out to me below, I understood that I could just create an AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress in my app Cloudformation.  As I am using a VPC and the code huelbois posted is for classic, I can confirm that this works:

In RDS Cloudformation:

```
    "DbVpcSecurityGroup" : {
        "Type" : "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
        "Properties" : {
            "GroupDescription" : "Enable JDBC access on the configured port",
            "VpcId" : { "Ref" : "VpcId" },
            "SecurityGroupIngress" : [  ]
        }
    }
```

And in app Cloudformation:

```
  "specialRDSRule" : {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress",
      "Properties" : {
          "IpProtocol": "tcp",
          "FromPort": 5432,
          "ToPort": 5432,
          "GroupId": {"Ref": "DbSecurityGroupId"},
          "SourceSecurityGroupId": {"Ref": "InstanceSecurityGroup"}
      }
  }
```

where DbSecurityGroupId is the id of the group setup above (something like sg-27324c43) and is a parameter to the app Cloudformation document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to use already existing resources in a CloudFormation template, you can use the previously created ids, instead of Ref or GetAtt.

In your example, you can use:

> { "EC2SecurityGroupId": "sg-xxxNNN" }

where "sg-xxxNNN" is the id of your DB SecurityGroup (not sure of the DB SecurityGroup prefix, since we don't use EC2-classic but VPC).

I would recommend using a parameter for your SecurityGroup in your template.

*** update **

For your specific setup, I would use a "DBSecurityGroupIngress" resource, to add a new sg to your RDS instance.

In your first stack (RDS), you create an empty DBSecurityGroup like this:

```
"DBSecurityGroup": {
    "Type": "AWS::RDS::DBSecurityGroup",

    "Properties": {
        "EC2VpcId" : { "Ref" : "VpcId" },
        "DBSecurityGroupIngress": [],
        "GroupDescription"      : "Frontend Access"
    }
}
```

This DBSecurityGroup is refered to by the DBInstance. (I guess you have specific requisites for using DBSecurityGroup instead of VPCSecurityGroup).

In your App stack, you create a DBSecurityGroupIngress resource, which is a child of the DBSecurityGroup your created in the first stack:

```
"specialRDSRule" : {
    "Type":"AWS::RDS::DBSecurityGroupIngress",
    "Properties" : {
       "DBSecurityGroupName": "<the arn of the DBSecurityGroup>",  
       "CIDRIP": String,
       "EC2SecurityGroupId": String,
       "EC2SecurityGroupName": String,
       "EC2SecurityGroupOwnerId": String
    }   
}
```

You need the arn of the DBSecurityGroup, which is "arn:aws:rds:::secgrp:". The other parameters come from your App stack, not sure if you need everything (I don't do EC2-classic security groups, only VPC).

Reference : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-rds-security-group-ingress.html

We use the same mechanism with VPC SecurityGroups, with Ingress & Egress rules, so we can have two SG reference each-other.

Comment: But its the DB stack thats needs updating.  So that stack will need the id of the security group created in the app stack.  So my workflow will be: Day 0->Create RDS stack, Day-1->Step 1. Create App Stack, Step 2 update RDS stack with group id from App Stack.  Hoping to get around having to do Step 2...?

Comment: Is it possible to "add to the previously defined SG" in the app cloudformation?  DBSecurityGroupIngress in AWS::RDS::DBSecurityGroup is a declaration of all permitted security groups - so if two apps are already permitted, I will need to repeat those two security group ids, and add the one newly created in my app cloudformation document.  Its starting to sound like I need scripts to make this happen, which I am happy to do, but just wanted to check first I was not missing something.

Comment: Third time the charm, I hope... :)

Comment: No, you just add the new SG in the App stack. You don't need to repeat the previous assignment. In fact you don't have to create an empty DBSecurityGroupIngress list.

Comment: thank you for showing that i can create a SecurityGroupIngress for a named group.  I am also using vpc, and updated my question with cloudformation json that i can confirm works.

Comment: I just have implemented this kind of stuff recently, so your question rang a bell!